# How to set YUI datatable column width in percentage?

Tags: javascript, css, yui

In YUI, data table column width is set as

var myColumnDefs = [
            {key:"Date",formatter:YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatDate, sortable:true, width:100},
            {key:"To", sortable:true, width:10},
            {key:"From", sortable:true,width:70},
            {key:"Subject", sortable:true, }
        ];

Width is by default treated in Pixels. I want to take this width in %age.

Comment: YUI2 or 3? You should say. YUI2 is sooooo yesterday... and now I would have to check BOTH teh YUI2 and YUI3 docs and sources to find you an answer (won't do).

Comment: I'm too lazy to check - it's so much easier if you just TRY. Use 100, "100px" and "20%" and see which ones work. If no one gets hurt trying stuff is sometimes easier than doing research :-)